# define macro in C won't work

Tags: c, macros

I'm trying to make a macro in C that can tell if a char is a hex number ( 0-9 a-z A-Z)

```
#define _hex(x) (((x) >= "0" && (x) <= "9" )||( (x) >= "a" && (x) <= "z") || ((x) >= "A" && (x) <= "Z") ? "true" : "false")
```

This what I've come up with but it won't work with a loop like this

```
char a;
     for(a = "a" ; a < "z";a++){
        printf("%s  => %s",a, _hex(a));
     }
```

it gives an error

```
test.c:8: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
test.c:8: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
test.c:9: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
test.c:9: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
test.c:9: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
test.c:9: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
test.c:9: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
test.c:9: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

Comment: That is not what hex number means. A hex digit is in 0-9 or A-F. You are checking if a character is alphanumeric.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"a" is a pointer to a string "a". You want to compare the char to 'a' instead.

```
#define _hex(x) (((x) >= '0' && (x) <= '9' )||( (x) >= 'a' && (x) <= 'z') || ((x) >= 'A' && (x) <= 'Z') ? "true" : "false")
```

But you can also use `isalnum(x)` instead - it returns true if the character is a digit or a character.

Or `isxdigit(x)` if it was really supposed to be a hex check.

Comment: my intention whas a-f ;p for HEX numbers :) but hadnt implemented in this example

Answer (score 2):

Use `isxdigit()` then.

Answer (score 1):

You have made the same error in your test loop as you did in the macro.

```
for(a = "a" ; a < "z";a++){
```

should be:

```
for(a = 'a' ; a < 'z'; a++){
```

And of course the sensible solution is to use `isxdigit()` defined in `ctype.h` as a macro (so you could take a look if you are interested).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change your "for" loop to loop over the range 'a' to 'z' instead of over the "a" to "z".

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest don't use macro for such functions. C99 supports inline functions just write

```
inline char *_hex(char c)
{
   ... write there what you need in readable form ...
}
```